# Printing ArrayList's Members

Tags: java, arraylist

The ArrayList, below, successfully prints its objects' fields, when the ArrayLists's reference variable "goes inside" System.out.println().

The output: [Dal:Tigers, SMU:Tigers, Acadia:Axemen]

The second ArrayList fails to print its objects' fields when its ArrayList reference "goes inside" System.out.println()...

why? I was surprised to even learn that an ArrayList's members could be printed by using an output method on the ArrayList's reference variable. What difference is there between the second code and the first one?

USport class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class USport {
    String school; // creates a field for String
    String name;  // creates a field for name
    public USport( String s, String n) // initializes school and name
    {school = s;
    name = n;}
    public String toString () // for use in output method; returns both
    {return school + ":" + name;}   
}

public class ArrayListDemo {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        ArrayList <USport> v = new ArrayList <> ();
        v.add( new USport ("Dal", "Tigers"));
        v.add( new USport ("SMU", "Tigers"));
        v.add( new USport ("Acadia", "Axemen"));

        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Cities class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class Cities {
    private String pub;
    private boolean pubHasDancing;

public Cities(String pub, boolean pubHasDancing){
    this.pub = pub;
    this.pubHasDancing = pubHasDancing;
}

public static void main(String[]args){  
    ArrayList <Cities> list2 = new ArrayList <> ();
    list2.add(new Cities ("Joce McCartney", false));
    list2.add(new Cities ("Paul McCartney", true));
    System.out.println(list2); // <<<<<< This is the method I'm questioning
    System.out.println(list2.get(1).pub);
    System.out.println(list2.toString()); /** <<<< This output should be the same as println's output no */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `USport` declares a `toString()` method that does the printing, and `Cities` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is: In the first class, you override the `toString()` method. However, you didn't do that in the second class. The `System.out.println()` will invoke the `ArrayList`'s `toString` method, which will invoke the `toString()` method of [`AbstractCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) class. So you need to override the `toString()` method of the second class in order to get the correct output.

```
@Override
public String toString () {
    return pub + ":" + pubHasDancing;
}
```

Comment: thanks -- the first class doesn't use the syntax you wrote. How did that class override toString()? When you say "override", you do mean that toString() supplanted System.out.println(). You don't mean that class 1 nullified toString and that System.out.println() was left unencumbered by its usual control flow, right?

Comment: @Override is just a hint to the compiler that the method will override its superclass' method. It is not related to println() method.